# How to control the height of descendant box within a nested flexbox context?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: green;
}
.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.columns.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.box22 {
  overflow: auto;
}
.box1 {
  background: red;
}
.box2 {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
.box222 {
  background: white;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<md-content class="md-padding">
  <div class="main columns vertical">
    <nav class="box1">nav</nav>
    <div class="box columns vertical">
      <div class="b">asdasd</div>
      <div class="box2 columns vertical">
        <div class="box21 columns">
          box21
        </div>
        <div class="box22 columns">
          <div class="box221">box221</div>
          <div class="box222">
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

I manually set the height of outermost box `main` and also set `box22` with `overflow:auto`, however the `box22` stretched out the `main` box and no scroll bar shows up.

What I want is to set height in the outermost box and the nested inner box can automitically control it's height thus all boxes are fitted. How to fix these kind of problem, should I set heights for all descendant boxes?

I tested setting `overflow :auto` at `box(level1)`, `box2(level2)` and `box22(level3)`, only `box(level1)` can automatically control it's height and shows up a scroll bar when it's height overlayed.

what I want is shown below, however, to achieve this, I need to manually specify the father box of `box22`. In other words, if I want to make a flex contaner scrollable, I have to at least set it's father box's height, which is toally unaccptable.

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: green;
}
.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.columns.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.box22 {
  overflow: auto;
}
.box1 {
  background: red;
}
.box2 {
  height:64px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
.box21 {
  background: yellow;
}
.box222 {
  background: white;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<md-content class="md-padding">
  <div class="main columns vertical">
    <nav class="box1">nav</nav>
    <div class="box columns vertical">
      <div class="b">asdasd</div>
      <div class="box2 columns vertical">
        <div class="box21 columns">
          box21
        </div>
        <div class="box22 columns">
          <div class="box221">box221</div>
          <div class="box222">
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: overflow:auto to `.columns.vertical` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif It didn't work.

Comment: Can you include a draw of your what you want yo achieve?

Comment: @guizo all boxes are included by the outer red box(Do not stretch out). if the children's height exceed, then a roll bar would show up. in this case the box22 should have a scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you noted, the parent container needs a height declaration in order to generate a scrollbar.

This makes sense because there's no way to trigger an overflow condition if there's no fixed length.

With a flexible length (e.g., `height: auto`), the container will shrink and expand to accommodate content, never triggering an overflow and, therefore, never generating a scrollbar.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) describes it like this:

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

So that's your obstacle. Here's how you get around it (knowing that you can't set more heights):

1. *Give the browser what it needs to trigger the overflow:* set a tiny (1px) height.
2. *You get the full height that you want:* use `flex-grow` to consume remaining space.

So something like this...

```
height: 1px;
flex-grow: 1;
```

but more efficiently:

```
flex: 1 0 1px; /* fg, fs, fb */
```

Add this to your code:

```
.main  .columns.vertical {
  flex: 1 0 1px;
}
.box22 {
  flex: 1 0 1px;
}
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: green;
}

/* NEW */
.main .columns.vertical {
  flex: 1 0 1px;
}

/* ADJUSTMENT */
.box22 {
  flex: 1 0 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.columns.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.box22 {
  flex: 1 0 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.box222 {
  background: white;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<md-content class="md-padding">
  <div class="main columns vertical">
    <nav class="box1">nav</nav>
    <div class="box columns vertical">
      <div class="b">asdasd</div>
      <div class="box2 columns vertical">
        <div class="box21 columns">box21</div>
        <div class="box22 columns">
          <div class="box221">box221</div>
          <div class="box222">
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Amazing, I also tested that only box22 need a initial height, other vertical columns can ommit the initial height. is this right?

Comment: By the way, there is one problem left, the height of box22 is the same as the remaining space instead  of the height of it's content, I posted this question here, though I already get one answer, would you  mind give some hint about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144971/how-to-make-flexboxs-with-cross-axis-overflow-have-the-same-height

Answer (score 0):

consider using max-height instead of height on main also... if you start with flexbox... best to keep display: flex through the whole chain

```css
.top {
  position: static;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flexcol {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.mynav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.box3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box221 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
}

.box222 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.darklink {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="flexcol">
    <nav class="mynav">
      <a class="darklink" href="#" target="_">Link1</a>
      <a class="darklink" href="#" target="_">Link2</a>
      <a class="darklink" href="#" target="_">Link3</a>
   </nav>
    <div class="box1">
      <p>para</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="box221">
        <p>para</p>
        <p>para</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box222">
        <p>para</p>
        <p>para</p>
        <p>para</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
      <p>para</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, box22 still stretches out and no scroll bar show up.

Comment: edited to include snippit to show the kind of thing i usually work with

Comment: I want some inner box to be srolled, not the outermost box.