# How to make flexbox with cross axis overflow have the same height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

A flex container contains two columns, and the first column could be with **any height**, so I manually set the height of the container and set `overflow: auto`.

What I expected is the right empty div would have the same height as the left `sss` box. It's true they have the same height, however it's due to the shrinked height of the left `sss` box.(The same height as the container 100px)

```css
.c {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.empty {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

.sss {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="sss">
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

I set `margin-top: auto` in the left box, now the height is back to normal (exactly the sum height of all `sss`) while the height of the empty box still remain the same.

```css
.c {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.empty {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

.sss {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="sss">
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I set `flex-wrap: wrap` and it worked, however I **don't want** them to be wrapped when the width is not enough.

Also, I tried to wrap these two columns in a table and the result is the same as `flex-nowrap`.

```css
.c {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.empty {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
}

.sss {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="sss">
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid instead:

```css
.c {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.empty {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.sss {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="sss">
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
    <p>sssss</p>
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the flex way doesn't work, why use `margin-auto` could make it streched?

Comment: @BAKEZQ margin is acually doing the opposite, the element is by default stretched to be equal to the parent height and adding margin you remove that restriction to allow it to grow with its content height

Comment: @BAKEZQ because it's empty. As I said, the margin will disable the stretch effect to make the element follow its content height. The empty div has no content so it will be 0 while the sss element is having content bigger than its parent and will fit it

Comment: Thanks I get this.. Still have two questions. 1. Except the grid way, are there any other way to achieve this with flex box? 2. why flex-nowrap could work?

Comment: @BAKEZQ with CSS grid it's easy as you can see, with flexbox it would be tricky and we may need to find workaround based on each case. Flex:wrap make it working because it create multiple lines where the empty div is on the first line and the height of that line is defined by with other div but as you said, element may got to next line if not enough space. Without wrap we have only one line defined by container height.